# Redirecting standard output to a file (once) works in Python 2.7 but not in Python 3.0?

Tags: python

Why does the following statement

```
print >> textfile, 'this is redirected output'
```

(where textfile = open('text.dat', 'a'))

work for redirecting standard output to a file in Python 2.7, but doesn't work in Python 3.0 ?

The error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\workspace\py\pypkg\redirection.py", line 19, in <module>
    print >> (textfile, 'this is redirected output')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function

Comment: Because `print()` in Python 3 is a function. Use `print('this is redirected output', file=textfile)` instead.

Comment: More details in the PEP: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/